# Javascript closure for "caching" a texbox value

Tags: javascript, closures

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJ3uU/5/) for the below code. What I'm trying to achieve is to get the value of "First textbox" always when clicking the first button and instead getting the actual value of "Second textbox" when clicking the second one but I'm not being able to do so. Any help on how to do it?

Javascript

```
  var mapping = function (id, refresh) {
     var ret = $(document.getElementById(id)).val(),
         func = function (refresh) {
             if (refresh) ret = $(document.getElementById(id)).text();
             return ret;
         };

     return {
         func: func
     };
 };

 var foo = {
     firstElement: function (refresh) {
         return new mapping('firstTextbox', refresh);
     },

     secondElement: function (refresh) {
         return new mapping('secondTextbox', refresh);
     }
 };

 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#firstButton').on('click', function () {
         $('#container').html(foo.firstElement(false));
     });

     $('#secondButton').on('click', function () {
         $('#container').html(foo.secondElement(true));
     });
 });
```

Html

```
<input type="textbox" id="firstTextbox" value="First textbox" />
<button id="firstButton">First button</button>
<br />
<input type="textbox" id="secondTextbox" value="Second textbox" />
<button id="secondButton">Second button</button>
<br />
<div id="container">Here comes the result</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your fillde and your code are different.

Comment: You shouldn't use `new` when the function is not a constructor but `return`s an object literal. Also notice that your `firstElement` and `secondElement` variables are undeliberately global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every click, you're calling `foo()` which does create a new `mapping` - which might not refresh from now on, but is initialized with the current value every time. Use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var getFirstElement = mapping('firstTextbox', false);
    var getSecondElement = mapping('secondTextbox', true);

    $('#firstButton').on('click', function () {
        $('#container').html(getFirstElement.func());
    });

    $('#secondButton').on('click', function () {
        $('#container').html(getSecondElement.func());
    });
});
```

[(updated demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/kJ3uU/4/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/kJ3uU/3/

```
$('#firstButton').on('click', function () {
     $('#container').text(foo.firstElement(false).func);
 });

 $('#secondButton').on('click', function () {
     $('#container').text(foo.secondElement(true).func);
 });
```

Also, in your fiddle you happened to have 'firstTextBox' string in both elements in your foo object.

Comment: You're right but your example stills makes an error. Thanks